# Magento2: Error 404 on homepage after migration and changing theme

Tags: magento2, migration, magento2.3.1, http-error-404

I migrated my data to a new magento v2.3.1 installation. Everything is working fine expect the homepage. I have set the cms page but the error still persists. When I view the page from Content > Pages it gives this error

```
{"0":"Notice: Undefined offset: -5867 in \/var\/www\/aslive\/lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/Search\/Dynamic\/Algorithm.php on line 302","1":"<pre>#1 Magento\\Framework\\Search\\Dynamic\\Algorithm->_findValueSeparator() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/Search\/Dynamic\/Algorithm.php:179]\n#2 Magento\\Framework\\Search\\Dynamic\\Algorithm->calculateSeparators() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/Search\/Dynamic\/Algorithm\/Improved.php:70]\n#3 Magento\\Framework\\Search\\Dynamic\\Algorithm\\Improved->getItems() called at [lib\/internal\/Magento\/Framework\/Search\/Adapter\/Mysql\/Aggregation\/Builder\/Dynamic.php:56]\
```

I have tried the solutions suggested here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11028 and here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6625 but I still can't get through.